# Check Network and Internet Connection - Android

Tags: java, android, android-internet

I was wondering if the method below check that I am both connected to a network, and can actually connected to the internet as well.

Not just connected to a network that won't let me access the internet ?

```
public boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = manager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

    boolean isAvailable = false;
    if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
        isAvailable = true;
    }
    return isAvailable;
}
```

I think, it does but I am not 100% sure.

Thanks

Comment: `networkInfo.isConnected()` checks whether network connectivity exists and if it is possible to establish connections and pass data.

You can also use `networkInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()` to check whether network connectivity exists or is in the process of being established.

Also, make sure you add permissions to your AndroidManifest.xml to access wifi and network state, respectively: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />`
    `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check internet access on Android? InetAddress never times out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560788/how-to-check-internet-access-on-android-inetaddress-never-times-out)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On comparing the accepted answer on this post to your code, what you are doing should work. Feel free to compare code. The safest thing to do  would be to run a few tests from airplane mode, with the WiFi turned off, and from a location away from WiFi just to be sure. Good luck.

[Android - Programmatically check internet connection and display dialog if notConnected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17880287/android-programmatically-check-internet-connection-and-display-dialog-if-notco)

Answer (score 2):

Have a look into [one of my old answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9570292/975292). It has two different methods 
1. to check if a device is connected to a network
2. to check if a device is connected to Internet.

Answer (score 0):

The code below will check the internet connectivity using kotlin in android studio:

```
private fun amIConnected(): Boolean {
    val connectivityManager = this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
    val activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.activeNetworkInfo
    return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the approach of [user:3156908](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31654999/boolean-android-net-networkinfo-isconnectedorconnecting-is-not-working-in-andr/41611537#41611537) but it kept crashing my app when the internet connection was off. Turns out there was a logical error on his code so i used the `connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null` to check for network details. In case the device is connected to  the network or it is in the process of connecting to the network use the `isConnectedOrConnecting()`

In your **AndroidManifest.xml** file add the following

```
<!--  Internet Permissions -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Create a method called `checkInternetConnection` in your **fragment class** or **Activity class** and add the following lines of code.

```
 @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    private boolean checkInternetConnection(){
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) mcontext.getSystemService(mcontext.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        return connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null
                && connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnectedOrConnecting();
    }
```

Then you can call the `checkInternetConnection` in your fragment's `onViewCreated` method or your activity's `onCreate` method.

**Note**
I would strongly advise you to test it the code when its connected to wifi, mobile data and airplane mode.