# boolean android.net.NetworkInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting() is not working in Android 5.1.1

Tags: android, android-5.1.1-lollipop

I am working on an Android Tablet Application, I am checking Internet connectivity within an Activity named "Home". I have tested the app in Android version 4.2 (Tablet), 4.4 (Tablet), 5.0 (Phone), 5.0.2 (Phone), the app is working fine.

**Problem:**
When I tested the app in Android 5.1.1 (Tablet), app is being forced close. Its showing following error in log.

**Log:**

```
2015-07-27 05:36:19.312 ERROR:  AndroidRuntime : java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.freestyle/com.freestyle.Home}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.net.NetworkInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()' on a null object reference
2015-07-27 05:36:19.312 ERROR:  AndroidRuntime : at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
2015-07-27 05:36:19.312 ERROR:  AndroidRuntime : at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
2015-07-27 05:36:19.312 ERROR:  AndroidRuntime : at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
2015-07-27 05:36:19.312 ERROR:  AndroidRuntime : at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
2015-07-27 05:36:19.312 ERROR:  AndroidRuntime : at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
2015-07-27 05:36:19.312 ERROR:  AndroidRuntime : at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
2015-07-27 05:36:19.312 ERROR:  AndroidRuntime : at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
2015-07-27 05:36:19.312 ERROR:  AndroidRuntime : at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
2015-07-27 05:36:19.312 ERROR:  AndroidRuntime : at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
2015-07-27 05:36:19.312 ERROR:  AndroidRuntime : at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
2015-07-27 05:36:19.312 ERROR:  AndroidRuntime : at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
2015-07-27 05:36:19.312 ERROR:  AndroidRuntime : Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.net.NetworkInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()' on a null object reference
2015-07-27 05:36:19.312 ERROR:  AndroidRuntime : at com.freestyle.utils.NetworkHelper.isConnectingToInternet(NetworkHelper.java:20)
2015-07-27 05:36:19.312 ERROR:  AndroidRuntime : at com.freestyle.Home.onCreate(Home.java:332)
2015-07-27 05:36:19.312 ERROR:  AndroidRuntime : at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
2015-07-27 05:36:19.312 ERROR:  AndroidRuntime : at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
2015-07-27 05:36:19.312 ERROR:  AndroidRuntime : at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
2015-07-27 05:36:19.312 ERROR:  AndroidRuntime : ... 10 more
2015-07-27 05:36:19.313 WARN:   ActivityManager : Force finishing activity 1 com.freestyle/.Home
2015-07-27 05:36:19.367 INFO:   OpenGLRenderer : Initialized EGL, version 1.4
2015-07-27 05:36:19.369 DEBUG:  mali_winsys : new_window_surface returns 0x3000
2015-07-27 05:36:19.383 DEBUG:  mali_winsys : new_window_surface returns 0x3000
2015-07-27 05:36:19.817 WARN:   ActivityManager : Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{2c5a4722 u0 com.freestyle/.Home t22999 f}
```

**Method to check Internet Connectivity:**

```
public boolean isConnectingToInternet() {
        boolean status = false;

            ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) _context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()
                    && cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable()
                    && cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()) {
                //have to assign true
                status = true;
                return status;
            }

        return status;
    }
```

**Code of Home Activity:**

```
public class Home extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    NetworkHelper nh = null;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    nh = new NetworkHelper(HomeActivity.this);

    if (nh.isConnectingToInternet()) {
            ApplicationUpdates app = new ApplicationUpdates(HomeActivity.this,
                    loadingString, updateMessage);
            app.fetchUpdate();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you get any solution?

Comment: Yes, Got the solution.

Comment: Will you please answer it here?

Comment: Sure.. I have posted now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I used below method

```
public static boolean isNetworkConnected(Context c) {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager =
        (ConnectivityManager) c.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
}
```

Comment: But above solution returns true even though Wifi is ON.

Comment: I needed active network whether it is Cellular Network or WiFi. Do you need only cellular network?

Comment: Got another idea.. have you tried using wake locks?
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.WifiLock

Answer (score 7):

check this way. Its work fine for mw

```
public static boolean checkInternetConnection(Context context)
    {
        try
        {
            ConnectivityManager conMgr = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

            if (conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null && conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable() && conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected())
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You have made logical mistake .. Actually your code is true.

```
public boolean isConnected(){
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    
   return ( networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting());
}
```

Comment: On if statement you need to check if it is null then you can check boolean .. Otherwise you will get null instead of boolean .

Comment: Yes. I need to do manage large operations only if Wifi is available & for smaller one I need Mobile N/W only

Answer (score 0):

```
ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo networkInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
if (networkInfo == null) {
    Toast.makeText(RefreshFunctionsActivity.this, "No save wifi detected.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin Extension function :-

```
fun Context.isNetworkConnected(): Boolean {
    val connectivityManager = this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as? ConnectivityManager
    val networkInfo = connectivityManager?.activeNetworkInfo

    return networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting
}
```