# How to show GPS and network alert dialog in whole application if network or GPS disable

Tags: android, android-gps

I want to show alert dialog in my android application if Network or GPS is disable, How it possible .please help me i am new for android

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use a broadcast receiver for network state changes & gps connectivity state changes, see: [Check INTENT internet connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3767591/check-intent-internet-connection) and [How can I check the current status of the GPS receiver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2021176/how-can-i-check-the-current-status-of-the-gps-receiver)

Answer (score 0):

The function (Boolean return) to test if GPS is enabled is:

```
String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);   
if(provider.contains("gps")) {}
```

To determine if Network is enabled (including dialog):

```
ConnectivityManager conMgr =  ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo netInfo = conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
if (netInfo == null){
    Description.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    new AlertDialog.Builder(WelcomePage.this)
        .setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
        .setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.internet_error))
        .setPositiveButton("OK", null).show();
}else{
    dialog = ProgressDialog.show(WelcomePage.this, "", "Loading...", true,false);
    new Welcome_Page().execute();
}
```

[Android - Programmatically check internet connection and display dialog if notConnected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17880287/android-programmatically-check-internet-connection-and-display-dialog-if-notco)