# App takes too long time stucks in white screen "freez UI" before show the full completed view

Tags: android, multithreading, performance, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

While I developing my app, I just noticed lately there's **GAP "too long time"** between start run the app and **displaying the full first view AKA Home fragment** It looks like there's something like blocking UI thread causes Lagging / White page when the app starts between 3 to 6 seconds in the real device and sometimes until 10 seconds in the emulator! at the average

The following GIF shows the problem

[image]

so I decided to measure the app launch time with two methods

**1. [The First method](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/launch-time)** is from google at the bottom of the documentation **"How to retrieve TTID"** section I filtered LogCat for `Displayed` and here is the results test of the emulator **PIXEL 6 PRO API 30**

```
2022-10-04 17:03:19.684   573-629   ActivityTaskManager     system_process  I  Displayed com.mml.dummyapp_kotlin/.ui.MainActivity: +17s522ms
2022-10-04 17:05:12.091   573-629   ActivityTaskManager     system_process  I  Displayed com.mml.dummyapp_kotlin/.ui.MainActivity: +12s611ms
2022-10-04 17:32:58.893   573-629   ActivityTaskManager     system_process  I  Displayed com.mml.dummyapp_kotlin/.ui.MainActivity: +14s860ms
```

the result of my real device API 30

```
2022-10-04 18:04:56.596  1619-2245  ActivityTaskManager     pid-1619  I  Displayed com.mml.dummyapp_kotlin/.ui.MainActivity: +13s218ms
2022-10-04 18:05:34.236  1619-2245  ActivityTaskManager     pid-1619  I  Displayed com.mml.dummyapp_kotlin/.ui.MainActivity: +9s882ms
2022-10-04 18:06:53.985  1619-2245  ActivityTaskManager     pid-1619  I  Displayed com.mml.dummyapp_kotlin/.ui.MainActivity: +23s329ms
```

the fully drawn results test of the emulator **PIXEL 6 PRO API 30**

```
2022-10-04 17:03:19.684   573-629   ActivityTaskManager     system_process  I  Fully drawn com.mml.dummyapp_kotlin/.ui.MainActivity: +17s522ms
2022-10-04 17:05:12.091   573-629   ActivityTaskManager     system_process  I  Fully drawn com.mml.dummyapp_kotlin/.ui.MainActivity: +12s611ms
2022-10-04 17:32:58.894   573-629   ActivityTaskManager     system_process  I  Fully drawn com.mml.dummyapp_kotlin/.ui.MainActivity: +14s860ms
```

the fully drawn results test of my device

```
2022-10-04 18:33:24.921  1619-2245  ActivityTaskManager     pid-1619  I  Fully drawn com.mml.dummyapp_kotlin/.ui.MainActivity: +4s403ms
2022-10-04 18:33:46.506  1619-2245  ActivityTaskManager     pid-1619  I  Fully drawn com.mml.dummyapp_kotlin/.ui.MainActivity: +3s577ms
2022-10-04 18:33:57.086  1619-2245  ActivityTaskManager     pid-1619  I  Fully drawn com.mml.dummyapp_kotlin/.ui.MainActivity: +3s459ms
```

**2. [The second method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33994484/4205927)** I created a var in onCreate of MainActivity `var APP_START_TIME: Long = 0` then I put the following code after `onViewCreated` of any fragment in the app

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        

        binding.root.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(object :
            ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {
            override fun onGlobalLayout() {
                binding.root.viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this)
                val launchTime: Long =
                    System.currentTimeMillis()
                        .minus((requireActivity() as MainActivity).APP_START_TIME)
                Log.e(TAG, "App launch time = $launchTime")
            }
        })

        Log.d(TAG, "onViewCreated: ${postViewModel.finalURL.value.toString()}")
```

and I got this result

```
E  App launch time = 2161
E  App launch time = 2572
E  App launch time = 2516
```

NOTE: This result measures from the onCreate till `onViewCreated` the first lagging (White Page time) is not counted

My app contains 2 Activities and 7 fragments, I converted all images from PNG to lightweight, and recommended version Webp, I have also some AdMob components, and I tried to wrap the Adview and other components related to it inside `CoroutineScope` with `Dispatchers.Unconfined` but this doesn't solve the issue

Here's The full **MainActivity** code

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    var APP_START_TIME: Long = 0


    private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration
    private var _binding: ActivityMainBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!
    private lateinit var navController: NavController
    private lateinit var postViewModel: PostViewModel
    private lateinit var settingsViewModel: SettingsViewModel
    private var _navGraph: NavGraph? = null
    private val navGraph get() = _navGraph!!
    lateinit var adView: AdView
    private var adRequest: AdRequest? = null


    private val applicationScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Unconfined)


    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()

        adView.destroy()
        adRequest = null
        _binding = null
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        APP_START_TIME = System.currentTimeMillis()
        adView = AdView(this)



        _binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        postViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this)[PostViewModel::
        class.java]
        settingsViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this)[SettingsViewModel::
        class.java]

        checkAndApplySelectedMode()




        setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbar)


        val drawerLayout: DrawerLayout = binding.drawerLayout


        val navHostFragment =
            supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment?

        if (navHostFragment != null) {
            navController = navHostFragment.navController
        }




        appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
            setOf(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_accessory,
                R.id.nav_arcade, R.id.nav_fashion,
                R.id.nav_food, R.id.nav_heath,
                R.id.nav_lifestyle, R.id.nav_sports, R.id.nav_favorites, R.id.settingsFragment
            ), drawerLayout
        )



        setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration)
        setupWithNavController(binding.navView, navController)

        _navGraph = navController.navInflater.inflate(R.navigation.mobile_navigation)


    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        delayedInit()
    }


    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        adView.pause()
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        adView.resume()

        postViewModel.currentDestination.observe(this) { currentDestination ->

            Log.w(TAG, "currentDestination: at first run is $currentDestination")

            navGraph.setStartDestination(currentDestination)
            navController.graph = navGraph


        }

        navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { _, destination, _ ->
            Log.d(TAG, "addOnDestinationChangedListener: " + destination.id)
            
            if (destination.id != R.id.settingsFragment
                && destination.id != R.id.aboutFragment
                && destination.id != R.id.privacyPolicyFragment
            ) {
                postViewModel.saveCurrentDestination(destination.id)
            }

        }
    }

    private fun requestHomeBanner() {

        adRequest = Constants.callAndBuildAdRequest()
        adView.adListener = object : AdListener() {

            override fun onAdFailedToLoad(adError: LoadAdError) {
                Log.e(TAG, "onAdFailedToLoad: ${adError.cause.toString()}")
                Log.e(TAG, "onAdFailedToLoad: ${adError.responseInfo.toString()}")
            }

        }

        adRequest?.let { adView.loadAd(it) }
    }

    private fun checkAndApplySelectedMode() {

        lifecycleScope.launch {
            settingsViewModel.getSelectedDayNightMode.observe(this@MainActivity) {
                Constants.applySelectedDayNightMode(it)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun delayedInit() = applicationScope.launch {
        binding.adViewContainer.addView(adView)
        adView.adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"
        adView.setAdSize(Constants.GET_AD_SIZE(this@MainActivity))


        val testDeviceIds = listOf("41A475886257209D2D2A19E53879CDBF")
        val configuration = RequestConfiguration.Builder().setTestDeviceIds(testDeviceIds).build()
        MobileAds.setRequestConfiguration(configuration)


        if (Utils.hasInternetConnection(this@MainActivity)) {
            requestTheLatestConsentInformation(this@MainActivity)
            MobileAds.initialize(this@MainActivity) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onInitCompleted")
            }

            requestHomeBanner()
        }
    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        return navController.navigateUp(appBarConfiguration) || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
    }

}
```

Comment: Not sure if helps but you may want to use a boolean check in `onResume()` to unsure it run once and once only. Consider putting a counter to debug it or better debug the time for each method took to load.

Comment: What is the content of `Utils.hasInternetConnection()`? Looks suspicious since you're calling it on the main thread.

Comment: @darkman `onResume()` of activity or fragment? do you think it's called twice? can you please show an example of what you mean?

Comment: @tenfour04 nothing suspicious it's just a method to check internet availability and load the adview like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59774931/7639296)